# Can libxslt-devel, po4a, asciidoc be installed on Redhat7,9 as SourceFile(tar)?

Tags: installation, rpm, yum

You must install in an environment where there is no network. Also, we would like to proceed with the installation on various OSes.

I want to `make intall` by downloading the source file and compiling it.

`libxslt-devel, po4a, asciidoc` three installations are required.

Do you know where I can get the source files or any helpful site with instructions on how to install them?

I'm still searching, but I can't find it, so I'm asking for help

Comment: If you do not have any network available, I think there's no other way but mounting the installation DVD of the OS, provided it also contains all the required sources packages.

Comment: thanks for the good comments. ```libxslt-devel``` was found on the DVD of OS. But the rest ```po4a``` and ```asciidoc``` were not.....

Comment: That's a common problem... they are available in the EPEL extension only AFAICS. So you should have a copy of this repository too, or at least of the packages you need. Maybe you can prepare an USB with all the requirements.

Comment: I'm still tring hard to find and fix it. It's not solved yet, but I'll try and learn.